# Circular dependency detected while autoloading a constant

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I upgraded Rails from version 3.1.2 (which worked fine) to 4.0, and got stuck with the following error:

```
circular dependency detected while autoloading constant Foo
```

I created a class `ProductFactory`, where I instantiate different models. For example:

```
p = Foo.new(params)
```

The model `"Foo"` is not always an ActiveRecord. Could anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: could you show how does your factory looks like? is Foo only inside methods? Or are you doing some metaprogramming? or assigning an array with classes to a different constant?

Comment: @IsmaelAbreu The structure of **ProductFactory** is as follows : based upon a condition (case..when) I assign a variable *p* with the reference to the object **p = Cat.new(params)** or **p = Dog.new(params)**. At the end of my function I return **p**.Also, My product Factory include  Singleton.

Comment: Where is the full stack trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of issues often happen when you change the version of Rails. You maybe didnt update the gems on the right order.

Comment: I don't know how/why but uninstalling and reinstalling all my gems in a different order worked... Thanks.

Comment: Is updating gem shot your problem?

Comment: I would love to see more of an explanation here. Also: how can this happen, when Rails is relying on bundler?

Answer (score 3):

Best I'm aware, circular dependencies error messages usually occur when cascading includes go wrong by recursively requiring a file before it is fully loaded, e.g.:

```
# File A:
require 'B'
module Foo; end

# File B:
require 'A'
module Foo; end
```

Any odds this is the kind of situation you're ending up with?

Comment: A lot of times something like  `lat, lon = Latitude.new, Longitude.new` will throw this error as well, if both `Latitude` and `Longitude` happen to inherit from the same class, like say `Coordinate`

Answer (score 3):

I had this error because I manually renamed controllers, routes etc etc and forgot to rename it in the first line of the files.

Was named

class AController < ApplicationController

instead of

class ARenamedController < ApplicationController

and I had gone and renamed all the other files individuall.

Not best practice I know, but I am learning and figuring it out, and in this case created the error this person is talking about. So if you got here through Google like I did, there is my solution.

Comment: Happened to me after I renamed a module, but forgot to change the **filenames**.