# Rails:Apache:Passenger: Circular Dependency Error, A DeviseController (RuntimeError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, devise, passenger

I'm trying to deploy my rails app on my VPS but I get the error in `/var/log/httpd/error_log` saying

```
`Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant DeviseController     (RuntimeError)
/home/user/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:509:in 'load_missing_constant'
/home/user/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:203:in 'const_missing'
/home/user/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/gems/devise-4.2.1/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb:1:in '<top (required)>'....`
```

I have searched Google and Bing and getting nowhere. I don't fully understand this error either. Created a base rails app and it worked. Reckoning that saying all is fine system-wide. The devise gem is installed on the system and have ran `bundler install` and no errors. Also ran `rake db:migrate` to install everything in the database. I suspect everything fine on the system but something in my app is wrong or I need to add something in devise but what??

In my app, its very simple. The app allows people to register and login. I do not use the mailing feature and it only has the standard `user` membership that devise use. Have not setup the admin role in devise. Its all default configurations.

Just in case my Apache config is

```
`<VirtualHost myapp.tk:80>
    ServerName myapp.tk
    ServerAlias www.myapp.tk
    DocumentRoot "/srv/http/myapp/public"
    ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/myapp.tk-error_log"
    CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/myapp.tk-access_log" common
    PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby
    RailsEnv production
    <Directory "/srv/http/myapp/public">
      Allow from all
      Options -MultiViews
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>`
```

The server setup is Apache/Passenger running on Archlinux. All are the latest  versions including the gems.

Let me know if I missed any log files or information needed. Seemed like a simple problem but

Answer (score 0):

You can try add this

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

Ruby looks for the file in the directories listed in $LOAD_PATH. That is, Ruby iterates over all its directories and for each one of them checks whether they have a file called "erb.rb", or "erb.so". If it finds any of them, the interpreter loads it and ends the search. Otherwise, it tries again in the next directory of the list. If the list gets exhausted, LoadError is raised.

```
inject Rack::Lock if config.eager_load is false
```

If code is not eager loaded constants are loaded on demand. Constant
autoloading is not thread-safe, so if eager loading is not enabled
multi-threading should not be allowed

Comment: Sorry, but what file or files would I add these lines?

Comment: You can add this first line to `config/application.rb`

Comment: Thank you for replying. I added it to the file and restarted the app 'touch tmp/restart.txt' and restarted apache but still getting the error without any changes.

Comment: Can you also check models namespace ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18921079/circular-dependency-detected-while-autoloading-a-constant?rq=1

Comment: Update: still not working but is working when I set it to development in the apache virtual host file. I have ran the `RAKE_ENV=production rake db:migrate` and `db:seed`. I'm thinking of deleting this post and coming back to it at a later time. Really not understanding why this isn't working in production mode. :/